# How to display multiple data from the same table depending on one column value

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT ModuleID 
  FROM tblActivity
 Where (Day = 2 And Day = 3 )
```

In here I am trying to display ModuleID which are on days Tuesdays(2) and Wednesday (3). All information are stored in the same table. When I execute this it just displays Module ID as a column and no data underneath it.

Comment: Can day really be 2 AND 3? Don't you intend to use OR in this case?

Comment: d. List the modules that are taught on a Tuesday and Wednesday    -Question Itself

Comment: Could you provide some data from the table? A few example rows.

Comment: @Arg0n is right! your interpretation of it is wrong. a column in a row can never have to values at same time hence `(Day = 2 And Day = 3 )` will evaluate to nothing ALWAYS the correct way is to use an OR statement  `(Day = 2 OR Day = 3 )`

Comment: Ohh yeah apologies for that the question mentioned And so I assumed it would be an and statement but its actually OR, sorry im new to SQL. Thanks

Comment: Like the other guys are saying, you should use the OR logic. But another option is to use the IN(some set) statement. So your WHERE clause would look like: WHERE Day IN(2,3) . That way if you wanted to add many Days then you could just do WHERE Day IN (2,3,4,5) instead of having to have a bunch of OR conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A where statement is evaluated by `ROW` so consider the following example:

```
ModuleId       Day
1               1
2               2
3               3
4               4
5               2
6               2
7               3
```

To attend your request on this set of data the result would be 2, 3, 5, 6 and 7 for ModuleId

When the database evaluate the where condition it will do by `ROW` so when you say `(Day = 2 And Day=3)` it will test each row like this:

```
1               1   is day=2 - false AND is day=3 - false
2               2   is day=2 - TRUE  AND is day=3 - FALSE | TRUE and FALSE = FALSE
3               3   is day=2 - false AND is day=3 - TRUE  | FALSE and TRUE = FALSE
4               4   is day=2 - false AND is day=3 - false    and so on for next lines
5               2   is day=2 - false AND is day=3 - false
6               2   is day=2 - false AND is day=3 - false
7               3   is day=2 - false AND is day=3 - false
```

That's why you have to use OR

```
select ModuleID
  from tblActivity
 where days = 2 or days = 3
```

Which will evaluate as

```
1               1   is day=2 - false OR is day=3 - false > FALSE
2               2   is day=2 - TRUE  OR is day=3 - FALSE | TRUE OR FALSE = TRUE
3               3   is day=2 - false OR is day=3 - TRUE  | FALSE OR TRUE = TRUE
4               4   is day=2 - false OR is day=3 - false    and so on for next lines
5               2   is day=2 - false OR is day=3 - false
6               2   is day=2 - false OR is day=3 - false
7               3   is day=2 - false OR is day=3 - false
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7c5b0/1

As mentioned in comments you can use the `IN` operator so:

```
select ModuleID
  from tblActivity
 where days IN (2, 3)
```

See it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7c5b0/2

Answer (score 0):

you should use OR instead of AND.
you can also use IN as given below

```
SELECT ModuleID 
  FROM tblActivity
Where Day IN (2,3)
```