# Oracle Group By expression not valid

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I tried to retrieve some results from a query in my Oracle tables.

The objective is to retrieve the total amount of prize money won by all competitors that belong to 3 countries:

This is my current query:

```
SELECT NATIONALITY, TOTALPRIZEMONEY
FROM COMPETITOR
WHERE NATIONALITY ='USA'
AND NATIONALITY = 'AUSTRALIA'
AND NATIONALITY = 'SINGAPORE'
GROUP BY NATIONALITY;
```

Below is a screenshot of my table structure:

[image]

I am getting the error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

May I request help in this question? Thank you

Comment: To `SELECT` a field it must either be in your `GROUP BY` or be an aggregate.   `SELECT NATIONALITY, SUM(TOTALPRIZEMONEY)` ***or*** `GROUP BY NATIONALITY, TOTALPRIZEMONEY`.

Comment: @MatBailie You are totally right and rather than the provided answer your comment is the bets explanation. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is used with aggregate queries. For example...

```
SELECT NATIONALITY, sum(TOTALPRIZEMONEY)
FROM COMPETITOR
WHERE NATIONALITY IN ('USA', 'AUSTRALIA', 'SINGAPORE')
GROUP BY NATIONALITY;
```

In your query, you aren't aggregating anything, therefore, there is no reason to `GROUP BY`.

From Oracle documentation on GROUP BY

> A GROUP BY clause, part of a SelectExpression, groups a result into subsets that have matching values for one or more columns. In each group, no two rows have the same value for the grouping column or columns. NULLs are considered equivalent for grouping purposes.
>
> You typically use a GROUP BY clause in conjunction with an aggregate
> expression.

Comment: That's not entiry true. You can use group by without an aggregate function, you just need to add all fields of the select on the group by clause!

Comment: @Drumbeg thank you for the help. However, I am receiving empty colums in the results. The query is able to run but results are not being shown.

Comment: @gymcode - That's because you have `Nationality = 'x' AND Nationality = 'y'`.  But no one row can ever be both, and so no one row ever passes your WHERE clause's criteria.  I expect you mean `Nationality = 'x' OR Nationality = 'y'` or perhaps you could use `Nationality IN ('x', 'y', 'z')`

Comment: WHERE NATIONALITY IN ('USA','AUSTRALIA','SINGAPORE')

Comment: Whoops. Missed that. Have added to the query.

Comment: @gymcode check out this answer to a detailed explanation on your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33834473/460557

Answer (score 1):

The correct query looks more like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TOTALPRIZEMONEY)
FROM COMPETITOR
WHERE NATIONALITY IN ('USA', 'AUSTRALIA', 'SINGAPORE');
```

You only need the `GROUP BY` if you want the results broken out by nationality.